# Prevent users from joining the survey multiple times using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

For example, we have a Web site. We have added surveys to our site.
Surveys will be attended by users on our website.

We have a database as follows.
There are 3 tables as users, surveys and surveyParticipation.

```
users
->userID         (int)
->username       (varchar(45))
->password       (varchar(45))
->email          (varchar(45))
->firstname      (varchar(45))
->lastname       (varchar(45))

surveys
 ->surveyNumber       (int)
 ->questionNumber     (int)
 ->question           (varchar(500))

surveyParticipation
 ->surveyNumber       (from the surveys table)
 ->userID             (from the users table)
```

I want to do the following operations only with mysql (phpmyadmin) without using any programming language;

**1-) one member can participate in more than one questionnaire (but each member can participate only once in a survey)**

for example ;

**surveyParticipation table**

```
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     1
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     2
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     3
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     4
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     5
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     6
 surveyNumber:1   userID:     7
 surveyNumber:2   userID:     1
 surveyNumber:2   userID:     2
 surveyNumber:2   userID:     3
 surveyNumber:2   userID:     4
 surveyNumber:2   userID:     1  (This user has joined more than once! How do I prevent it)
```

do you help me solve my problem?

Comment: Add a unique index on both of the columns in the `surveyParticipation`-table?

Comment: If I do so, only one member can participate in a survey.

Comment: You'd normally just form a composite PRIMARY KEY on (surveyNumber,userID)

Comment: Well, I solved the problem.
thank you.    @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique constraint on `surveynumber` and `userid` in `surveyparticipation`.

```
ALTER TABLE surveyparticipation
            ADD UNIQUE (surveynumber,
                        userid);
```

Or, since the table apparently has none but should have one, make it a primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE surveyparticipation
            ADD PRIMARY KEY (surveynumber,
                             userid);
```

Primary keys have to be unique too, so this also works. And nulls don't seem to makes sense in `surveynumber` nor `userid`, so the implicit not null constraint coming with it doesn't harm either.

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem for 24 hours.
I solved the problem with **your help**.
Thanks.